# Starting server in rails app dont lead me on the root page. Prototyp.js error occurs in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, aptana, radrails

Some months ago I tried out Aptana RadRails but I changed back to Sublime.

Now whenever I start a my Application I get the following console log errors, but on `localhost:3000` I see "Welcome to Aptana RadRails" and apart from the root problem the Application works still fine.

I don't know why this happens, because the root in my routes is a totally different site. It tells me prototyp.js, rails.png and effects.js are missing but I never used them.

Error in the console:

```
Started GET "/images/rails.png" for ::1 at 2015-07-09 00:21:36 +0200  
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (15.0ms)  SELECT
"schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/rails.png"):   actionpack (4.2.0)
lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'   web-console (2.1.2)
lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'   actionpack (4.2.0)
lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'   railties (4.2.0)
lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'   railties (4.2.0)
lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'   activesupport (4.2.0)
lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'   activesupport (4.2.0)
lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'   activesupport (4.2.0)
lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'   railties (4.2.0)
lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'   actionpack (4.2.0)
lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'   rack (1.6.0)
lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'   rack (1.6.0)
lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'   activesupport (4.2.0)
lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'   rack (1.6.0)
lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'   actionpack (4.2.0)
lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'   rack (1.6.0)
lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'   railties (4.2.0)
lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'   railties (4.2.0)
lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'   rack (1.6.0)
lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'   rack (1.6.0)
lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'   rack (1.6.0)
lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'  
/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'  
/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'  
/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: You need to add more details about your environment and how you start your application for us to have a hope of being able to help you here.

Comment: I added now the console log. Anything else i could add?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the root page is overridden by a static file - delete `public/index.html` if there is such a file inside the app folder.

(It's the default welcome page and it's supposed to be deleted once you have some route mapped to the root page)